# How to set css system fonts for serif'd fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, typography, system-font

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/
Found this awesome link on how to make leverage system fonts.  This example only shows sans-serif:

```
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

Question: what would be the matching serif version of the snippet above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating systems generally don't use serif fonts like that, unless set explicitly by the user, so `-apple-system` won't have a serif version, but you can just use `serif` (without the other fonts you have listed) to use the browser's default serif font.